# Why is my ruby script execution too long?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

I am trying to solve a problem from http://www.beatmycode.com/challenge/5/take, and I wrote a script:

```
def is_prime?(num)
  (2...num).each do |divisor|
    return false if num % divisor == 0
  end
  true
end
def circular_prime(num)
  circular_primes = [] 
  if num < 2
    return false
  end
  (2..num-1).each do |number|
    is_prime?(number)
    result = [number.to_s]
    (0..number.to_s.size-2).each do |x|
      var = result.last.split('')
      result << var.unshift(var.pop).join if var.uniq.size != 1
    end
    circular_primes << result if result.all?{ |x| is_prime? x.to_i }
  end
end
```

When I tested it with `10`,`100`,`1000`, and `10_000`, the script executed very fast, but when I tested with `100_000`, the shell displayed an `Interrupt` error. Where is the weak point, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `is_prime?` method is too slow. Some minor improvement could be:

- You don't have to test `divisor` all the way upto `num`, the square root of
  `num` is enough.
- You can skip all even numbers since `2` is the only even prime
  number.

However, this is still not good enough because the algorithm is slow. Since you need to generate prime numbers among consecutive integers, consider using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

---

Of course there's [`prime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/prime/rdoc/index.html) standard library but I assume you want to do this manually.

Comment: thank you, I know about `prime` lib in ruby.But I don't sure, can I use this library on beatmycode

Answer (score 0):

This script's time complexity is `O(n^2)`, so it's expected that it will take long time to finish for big input. Try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes to find primes and remembering which number is a prime in some array.